# How to edit or clear the MRU list of repositories in Tortoise SVN (Windows)

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

When I go to open the Tortoise Repository it shows me a list of all the Most Recently Used (MRU) repositories I've created (when testing). I'd like to remove those.

How can I edit that list?

Answer (score 4):

It's working path for me:

`RBM -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Saved Data -> URL history -> Clear`.

Or you can get cached repositories from:

`RBM -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Log Caching -> Cached Repositories`